# Error during the pulling of a Docker's image: Error response from daemon: manifest for... not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker

I'm trying to download the [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gascountkomat/updated-anatomia-del-gray-pdf-italiano#anatomia%20gray%20pdf%20italiano):

docker pull gascountkomat/updated-anatomia-del-gray-pdf-italiano

in Ubuntu 20.04, but the terminal gives me the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manifest unknown error indicates the container image you are trying to pull does not exist.

The requested repo is showing 0 pulls in the UI:

[image: pull count of 0]

The same shows via the API:

```
$ curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/gascountkomat/updated-anatomia-del-gray-pdf-italiano | jq .
{
  "user": "gascountkomat",
  "name": "updated-anatomia-del-gray-pdf-italiano",
  "namespace": "gascountkomat",
  "repository_type": null,
  "status": 0,
  "status_description": "initialized",
  "description": "Anatomia Del Gray Pdf Italiano",
  "is_private": false,
  "is_automated": false,
  "star_count": 0,
  "pull_count": 0,
  "last_updated": "2021-05-01T20:01:51.879675Z",
  "date_registered": "2021-05-01T20:01:51.879675Z",
  "collaborator_count": 0,
  "affiliation": null,
  "hub_user": "gascountkomat",
  "has_starred": false,
  "full_description": "<ol><li><a href='#anatomia gray pdf italiano'>anatomia gray pdf italiano</a></li>\n<li><a href='#'></a></li></ol>\n<p><br></p>\n<p><a href=\"https://bytlly.com/1w8sn2\"><img src=\"http://www.marysrosaries.com/collaboration/images/thumb/a/a3/Respiratory_system_complete_Fran%C3%A7ais_French.pdf/page1-527px-Respiratory_system_complete_Fran%C3%A7ais_French.pdf.jpg\"></a></p>\n<p><br></p>\n<p><a href=\"https://bytlly.com/1w8sn2\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/g/greathigh-power/20200126/20200126194015.jpg\" alt=\"Anatomia Del Gray Pdf Italiano\" /></a></p><br>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p><br></p>\n<p><h2 id='anatomia gray pdf italiano'></h2></p>\n\n<p>La Chiarezza E Il Fascino Dell Anatomia: Anatomia Del Gray. Le Basi Anatomiche ... anatomia del gray pdf italiano - Darin Smalls. Welcome to .... Guida All'atlante Di Anatomia Umana Pdf Ita PDF ... L'anatomia: Anatomia del Gray Atlante di anatomia umana di Netter, Libro di Frank H.</p>\n<ol><li><a href='#anatomia gray pdf italiano'>anatomia gray pdf italiano</a></li>\n<li><a href='#'></a></li>\n<li><a href='#'></a></li></ol>\n<p>Through big data analysis, the tool can only recommend the following keyword data related \"Anatomia Del Gray Pdf Torrent.... Anatomia del Gray. Le basi anatomiche per la pratica clinica (Italian) Hardcover.</p>\n<h2 id='anatomia gray pdf italiano'>anatomia gray pdf italiano</h2>\n<p>anatomia gray pdf italiano, anatomia del gray download italiano</p>\n<p>PDF | Style is a familiar category for the analysis of art. ... Henry Gray's famous Anatomy of 1858, illustrated by Henry Vandyke ... drawn by Antonio Seratoni, from Anatomia universa Paolo Mascagni (1823–31). ... scheme of the Italian anatomist, Paolo Mascagni, more ... ´n del cuerpo humano, Jan Valverde.. Vendo i due volumi ANATOMIA DEL GRAY 40* pdf a colori del libro di anatomia gray. Tags: anatomia, gray, edizione, volumi. Bergamo.. thread, anatomia del gray le basi anatomiche per la pratica clinica 2 vol ... Ediz. illustrata pdf gratis italiano Leggere Online Valle d'Itria style.. Download Anatomia del Gray. Le basi anatomiche per la pratica clinica Pdf Gratis ITA Leggere.. Rangoon",
  "permissions": {
    "read": true,
    "write": false,
    "admin": false
  },
  "media_types": [],
  "content_types": []
}
```

Every image that is pushed to Hub gets pulled at least once by automated tooling, you'll see this after pushing your own images. So this is a sign that the repo has never had a container image pushed to it.

Judging by the other repos from this user, it looks like the profile is used to push spam content without any actual container images.

Answer (score 2):

Dockerhub [deletes](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-hub-image-retention-policy-delayed-and-subscription-updates/) images published by free account users that haven't been pulled in 6 months. Looks like all tags published for `gascountkomat/updated-anatomia-del-gray-pdf-italiano` image have been deleted, hence there are [no tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/gascountkomat/updated-anatomia-del-gray-pdf-italiano/tags) listed. When you do a `pull` without specifying a tag, the docker cli is looking for an image with the tag `latest` and as no such image(or image with any tag for that matter) exists, you are seeing the `not found` error.

Comment: From the link you shared, there's no automatic image deletion: "Today’s announcement means Docker will not enforce image expiration enforcement on November 1."

Comment: Hello @BMitch is there a way to recover that image?

Comment: @BMitch Image expiration was originally supposed to go into effect in Nov-2020, it was postponed till mid 2021. It has gone into effect since then

Comment: @devatherock I don't believe docker has actually enabled that policy. I still have images that haven't been pulled in over 3 years on Hub. Judging by the linked repo, it shows 0 pulls, so I don't believe any images were ever pushed to that repo.